# jQuery, how to trigger an href click on when a parent row is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a table and in each row is an an anchor element.  How would I go about triggering the click of the href if the parent row is clicked anywhere in the row?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried $('row a').click(); haven't you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890743/click-entire-row-preserving-middle-click-and-ctrlclick

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean a table row, the you would add a click handler to the row that simply clicked the child `a` tag:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).children("td > a").click();
    return false; // Prevent event propagation and infinite loops
});
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to Tatu for reminding me about event propagation

Comment: This can't work, since a tr element must have td elements as children. You are better served using the .find() method.

Comment: You caught me! I edited my answer to more correctly match the idea I was trying to get across. But you're right - using .find() would be easier since you don't need to know the structure of your `td` element to get the `a` element, especially if you use a more specific selector (ie specify the class of the `a`).

Comment: Didn't work and I got this 
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`