# How to navigate in JSF page?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to create h:datatable with list of data:

```html
<h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
    <!-- Check box -->
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Select" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  onclick="highlight(this)"
                value="#{item.selected}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink value="№"
                    actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                    <f:attribute name="№" value="№" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText
                value="#{table.rowIndex + SessionsController.firstRow + 1}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID"
                    actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                    <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink value="User ID"
                    actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                    <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time"
                    actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                    <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time"
                    actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                    <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink value="Activity"
                    actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                    <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

I want when I click on a table row to open a new page which displays more details. I want to use the table key `aSessionID` which will be used for SQL query to get a data from the database. I know that I can use `h:commandLink` to pass the key but I don't want ugly html link. Is there other way to click on the JSF table row, pass a key and open a new window?

Best Wishes

**EDIT**

I found one possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890743/click-entire-row-preserving-middle-click-and-ctrlclick)

Using this JavaScript code it's possible to open a new window when the user clicks on a row:

```
<table id="row_link"> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr>
      <td><a href="link1.html">link</a></td> 
      <td>info 1</td> 
    </tr>       
    <tr>
      <td><a href="link2.html">link</a></td> 
      <td>info 2</td> 
    </tr>       
  </tbody> 
</table>

$("table#row_link tbody tr").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).find("a:first").attr("href");
});
```

The question is how I can pass this key `aSessionID` to the new window. 
In the above example `href` is used to pass the link to the new window. What attribute can be used in JSF table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BalusC (JSF expert) has a post about managing Datatable in JSF 1.2 but it works for JSF 2.x too. You're interested in the [select row on click](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#HighlightAndSelectRowOnClick) section.

UPDATE:

Let me explain the example. First, every JSF component ID will have this form: :, example:

```html
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText id="myInputText" value="#{myBean.textValue}" />
</h:form>
```

This will generate the HTML:

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="myForm:myInputText" />
</form>
```

Second, you have to update the generated [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) for the datatable. He's doing that by javascript and also gives you the js code:

```
function addOnclickToDatatableRows() {
    //gets all the generated rows in the html table
    var trs = document.getElementById('form:dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
        .getElementsByTagName('tr');
    //on every row, add onclick function (this is what you're looking for)
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        trs[i].onclick = new Function("highlightAndSelectRow(this)");
    }
}
```

Third, define the `highlightAndSelectRow` js function (you can change the name to whatever you want).

```
function highlightAndSelectRow(tr) {
    //get all the datatable rows
    var trs = document.getElementById('form:dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
        .getElementsByTagName('tr');
    //find the selected rowby using the tr parameter
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        if (trs[i] == tr) {
            //once found it, change the color (maybe you don't need this part)
            trs[i].bgColor = '#ff0000';
            //update a hidden value in the form (maybe you need this code)
            document.form.rowIndex.value = trs[i].rowIndex;
            //here, you can add js code to open a new window
            //or simulate a button/link click or something else you need.
        } else {
            trs[i].bgColor = '#ffffff';
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I've made a test for this case. I'll show you the code to get it done using facelets.

DataTable.xhtml

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addOnclickToDatatableRows() {
        //gets all the generated rows in the html table
        var trs = document.getElementById('myForm:dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
            .getElementsByTagName('tr');
        //on every row, add onclick function (this is what you're looking for)
        for (var i = 0; trs.length > i; i++) {
            trs[i].onclick = new Function("rowOnclick(this)");
        }
    }

    function rowOnclick(tr) {
        var elements = tr.cells[0].childNodes;
        for(var i = 0; elements.length > i; i++) {
            //get the link
            if ((typeof elements[i].id !== "undefined") &amp;&amp;
                (elements[i].id.indexOf("lnkHidden") > -1)) {
                //open a new window/tab using the href generated in link
                window.open(elements[i].href);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>

<h:form id="myForm">
    <h1>Show data</h1>
    <h:dataTable id="dataTable" var="data" value="#{datatableBean.lstData}">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="ID" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{data.id}" />
            <!-- define a hidden link for every row of the datatable
                 the value attribute contains the page to redirect. -->
            <h:outputLink id="lnkHidden" value="AnotherPage.xhtml"
                            style="display:none">
                <f:param name="id" value="#{data.id}" />
            </h:outputLink>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Value" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{data.value}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

DataTableBean class

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DatatableBean {

    private List<Data> lstData;
    /**
    * Creates a new instance of datatableBean
    */
    public DatatableBean() {
        lstData = new ArrayList<Data>();
        lstData.add(new Data(1, "Hello World"));
        lstData.add(new Data(2, "Hello StackOverflow"));
        lstData.add(new Data(3, "Hello Luiggi"));
        System.out.println("LOL");
    }
    //define getters and setters...
}
```

AnotherPage.xhtml

```html
<h1>This is another page</h1>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="Selected ID" />
    <h:outputText value="#{anotherPageBean.id}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

AnotherPageBean class

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AnotherPageBean {

    private int id;
    /**
    * Creates a new instance of AnotherPageBean
    */
    public AnotherPageBean() {
        try {
            this.id = Integer.parseInt((String)FacesContext
               .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
               .getRequestParameterMap().get("id"));
            //by getting the id you can get more data
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            this.id = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this example can be used.

Comment: As far as I see if I add this code when I select a row the row will be just highlighted. I need to open a new page when I select the row.

Comment: @PeterPenzov that's what I've told you in the js comments

Comment: I updated the post. I found easy solution to my problem but I don't know how to edit the JSF table. In the example that I found "href" is used to tell the JavaScript which web page to open. is there a similar attribute in JSF which I can use?

Comment: @PeterPenzov http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/

Comment: what is this in into the function rowOnclick? -  &amp;&amp; Maybe you mean '&&'?

Comment: If you have a working example would you upload it for example here, please http://www.2shared.com/  I would like to see how it works.

Comment: @PeterPenzov I've uploaded the sources here http://www.2shared.com/file/2HSzkdAY/DataTableExample.html

Comment: @PeterPenzov in facelets its not permitted the & symbol, that's why i wrote &amp; twice to simulate &&

Comment: Well, Netbeans gives many errors. Anyway, thank you the example works!

Comment: One more question, how I can modify the code instead of opening new page when I click on a row - I wan to open a new page in the same window.

Comment: @PeterPenzov `window.open('elements[i].href','_self')` or `location.href=elements[i].href` any of those will do the work.

Comment: I want to ask one more question: I tested the example, it works fine. I saw that the value is passed using the http header. Example: http://localhost:8080/test/AnotherPage.xhtml?id=2 Is there any other way to pass this value somehow hidden from the user?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you can achieve it by using a `h:commandLink` instead of `h:outputLink` and send the parameter via session scope in the action method.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in @ViewScope?

Comment: One interesting question: If I configure the managed bean in faces-config.xml in ViewScope and I place @SessionScope into the bean body is it going to work?