# How to allow 'Open in a new tab' when using ng-click?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a table on HTML and each row leads to a different page, with more details about that row. But as I am using angularjs, with ng-click I can't right click this row and select 'open in a new tab'. Is there any way to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read this yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757837/when-click-a-button-then-open-a-new-tab-in-angular-js

Comment: Yep, but that is not my problem. I dont want to ALWAYS open in a new tab, but with ng-clik this window doesn't appear when you right-click the row: http://puu.sh/88Mbz.png

Comment: what about let the browser manage this when right click?

Comment: That was all that I wanted, but the browser isn't managing. this is what happens when right click the row http://puu.sh/88Nss.png. It doesn't interpret as a link.

Comment: You should convert your element to href `<a ng-href"{{your dynamic url}}" ng-click="your function">`. Not only do you have to show the correct dropdown, but also have a correct href value to open in a new tab.

Comment: No problem @jgabrielfaria, added a answer, and would appreciate it if you marked it as correct answer 8-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**If possible you should convert your element to an anchor element.**

```
<a ng-href="{{ your dynamic url }}" ng-click="your function">Your link text</a>
```

The browser will interpret the element as a link, and will therefor give you the correct dropdown. 
Note that you also have to have the correct href value to open in a new tab.

**EDIT:**
I would recommend [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890743/click-entire-row-preserving-middle-click-and-ctrlclick) if you want a more detailed answer on how to fix this kind of behaviour using JQuery.

Comment: This is a little confusing. The example makes it sound like I need both `ng-href` and `ng-click` on the same element.

Comment: I can see that. But the question was "How to allow 'Open in a new tab' when using ng-click?" Interrpeted it as he wanted to have the 'Open in a new tab' option on a element that also used ng-click.

Comment: You would only need either ng-click or ng-href , if you want both of them to open the link in a new tab .
  The angularJS code checks if the browser URL is same as the one on the ng-href and switches urls if they are not .

Comment: This may technically work, but Chrome blocks this as a pop-up. Most users are not savvy enough to notice this and permit the site, so be wary about your user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your ng-click function you can call `window.open(url, '_blank')` however as a **word of warning**, this will depend on the browser and current settings.

In some cases this will open in a pop-out window and in other cases it will open in a new tab. There is no way to force either behavior as the javascript is browser agnostic, it has simply requested a new window and it is up to the browser the decide how to implement it. [see here for a discussion on forcing a tab or window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

However the only way to get that right-click option or the ctrl+click to open in a new tab is if the browser sees a `<a>` tag. Otherwise it doesn't treat it as a link.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate your `href` dynamically based on some condition then you can set your `href` on `ng-mousedown` event and after that you can perform any event like `open link in new tab`, `open link in new window` and `click`.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-mousedown="openDetailView($event, userRole)">{{label}}</a>
```

**JS :**

```
  $scope.openDetailView = function (event, userRole) {
         if(userRole == 'admin') {
             jQuery(event.target).attr('href', 'admin/view');

         } else {
             jQuery(event.target).attr('href', 'user/view');

         }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use anchor element inside the table row.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <a ng-href="dynamic url" ng-click="openItem($event)">Open the item</a>
</tr>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.openItem = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // code to open a item
}
```