# ng-click doesn't open new windows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a table in which the last column contains buttons that should open a new window but they don't.
Here is my code:

```
<table class="table  table-hover" id="angular_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="company">Nome azienda&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('company')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th class="code">Codice&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('code')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th class="projectName">Nome progetto&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('projectName')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th class="recordType">Tipo di record&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('recordType')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>                            
      <th class="year">Anno&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('year')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th class="month">Mese&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('month')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th>Crea ricavo&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>                        
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query:checkEqual | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse " id="lista">
      <td>{{item.company}}</td>
      <td >{{item.code}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: -webkit-left;"> <a href="/{{item.id}}" target="_blank">{{item.projectName}}</a></td>
      <td>{{item.recordType}}</td>                            
      <td>{{item.year}}</td>
      <td>{{item.month}}</td>
      <td class="btnCrea"><button class="btn2 btn-default2" ng-click="window.open('/apex/creaRicavoM?id={{item.id}}','_blank','heigth=600,width=600')">Crea</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your browser block popups? Check the URL bar when you click the button to make sure that it doesn't.

Comment: You cannot access window out of scope. Angular expressions including functions are evaluated against scope. global objects are not accessible as is. Just bind it to a function on the controller and open it from there.

Comment: Duplicate of ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069481/how-to-allow-open-in-a-new-tab-when-using-ng-click

Comment: I imagine `window.[...]` is being evaluated as `$scope.window.[...]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please define the function into $scope or $rootScope, and call that function on ng-click.

Example :

in $scope

```
$scope.openurl = function(url){
    window.open(url, '_blank','heigth=600,width=600');   // may alse try $window
}
```

Or

in $rootScope

```
 $rootScope.openurl = function(url){
        window.open(url, '_blank','heigth=600,width=600');   // may alse try $window
    }
```

In html, Try this

```
 <td class="btnCrea"><button class="btn2 btn-default2" ng-click="openurl('/apex/creaRicavoM?id={{item.id}}')">Crea</button></td>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't vote your answer... It required at leat 15 reputation points, I have only 6 :(

Comment: When you will have 15 points and time, then do it. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Angular's `$window` service to access the window object from within an `ng-click` handler.

Within your controller, add a function to the scope, e.g.

```
$scope.popupWindow = function(itemId) {
    $window.open('/apex/creaRicavoM?id=' + itemId,'_blank','heigth=600,width=600');
}
```

And then in your template, you can use:

```
ng-click="popupWindow(item.id)"
```

Also, don't forget to inject `$window` into your controller.

Comment: can Javascripts `window` no be used directly ? this example shows that $window service is not required: http://plnkr.co/edit/fdHHrPiwWI1cbUcgdrYx?p=preview , is there any specific reason to use it ?

Comment: Actually, yes it can, though I've hit problems with window.alert() in the past messing with the digest cycle. Also, to quote the Angular docs... "While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing."

Comment: thats fair enough ! +1 for the more 'Angular way' answer then! :D

Comment: I've edited my answer to say "should" instead of "need to", as technically, you don't need to use $window :)

Comment: @Alan I got this error "ReferenceError: $window is not defined". I wrote in my controller this code: "contrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter','$window'];". Where am I wrong?

Comment: @DarkSkull have you passed `$window` into your function too ?

Comment: As @Pogrindis says, you'll need to use `var contrl = function($scope, $filter, $window) { ... };` as well. I never use $inject syntax myself, but I think what you've got there is correct otherwise.

Comment: Thank you guys! I resolved with rajeshpanwar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
        <td class="btnCrea"><button class="btn2 btn-default2" ng-click="viewLink(your URL)">Crea</button></td>
```

In controller :

```
        $scope.viewLink = function (url) {
    var ref = window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
}
```

Comment: This is all wrong..  Also the class is `viewLink` ? And the `ng-click` `openW` doesnt exist ??

Answer (score 0):

Read this answer [Open links in new window using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099784/open-links-in-new-window-using-angularjs)

You should bind your function to a controller or directive. Also use the Angular `$window` service instead of the `window` object

Answer (score -2):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Visit google!</a>
```

try this

Comment: this is not a solution when using `ngClick` the `target` attribute is ignored. This is just a plain HTML hyperlink