# Refering to a particular table row in html

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-table, row

I have five rows in my table in html. Each row has only 1 td. I want to manipulate the table row background in a function. How do I refer to the  table row in the function?

Comment: Would using CSS (as in this [stackoverflow question][1]) meet your requirement? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569355/html-table-row-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference them by their ordinal index;

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
var firstRow = tbl.rows[0];
...
tbl.rows[n].style.color = "red"; 
...
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows

Comment: :Can i do this: tbl.rows[1].bgcolor="red"

Comment: Yes, you can use a number, [0] is the first row, [1] the seconds and so on.

Comment: :in your example is "mytable" the name of the table or the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it an ID and use `document.getElementById("id");` or you can get it by tag name with `document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[x];`, where `x` is the number row (fifth row, `x=5`)